# Bootstrap validator on error handler not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using bootstrap validator on an ajax form in my asp.mvc 5 project:

```
$('#formID').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                ddd: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Campo requerido'
                        }
                    }
                },
                rede: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The amount is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                rede: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The color is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                tipo: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The size is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                obs: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The size is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).on('error', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Everything works, but after clicking on submit, the will still submit:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("InserirChamado", "ChamadoLLPP", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "FuncSucesso", OnFailure = "FuncError" }, new { @id = "formID" })){}
```

preventDefault(), stopPropagation() and return false won't work. How can make it stop submiting?

Comment: I think the on error event name is `err.form.bv` not `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `error.form.bv` and/or `success.form.bv` handler to handle form validation errors given by this example (see [event handling](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/event.html) as reference):

```
$('#formID').bootstrapValidator({
     feedbackIcons: {
         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
     },
     fields: {
         field1: {
            validators: {
                 notEmpty: {
                    message: 'This field cannot be empty'
                 }
            }
         },

         // other field validators
    }
 }).on('error.form.bv', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // prevent form submission if preventDefault() not working
      $('#formID').submit(false);

      // other validation error handlings

 }).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // other stuff

      $('#formID').bootstrapValidator('defaultSubmit');
 });
```

Additionally you can add `error.field.bv` and `status.field.bv` handlers to disable/enable submit button functionality:

```
$('#formID').bootstrapValidator({ 

    // validation settings, cut for brevity

}).on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true); // Disable submit button
}).on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false); // Enable submit button
});
```